Deeplink not opening the app with supabase google login react-native
I'm using supabase google login and below is how i handle google login.
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const data = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
        provider: 'google',
        options: {
          redirectTo: 'myapp://auth/callback',
        },
      });

      if (data.error) {
       // error handli
      } else {
        console.log('Data:', data);
        console.log('Redirecting to:', data.data.url);
        Linking.openURL(data.data.url);
      }
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

this opens the google account select on browser.
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Linking} from 'react-native';
import {handleDeepLink} from '../utils/handleDeepLink';

const useDeepLinking = async () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleURL = async ({url}: {url: string}) => {
      console.log(url)
      await handleDeepLink({url});
    };

    Linking.addEventListener('url', handleURL);
    Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
      if (url) {
        handleURL({url});
      }
    });

    return () => {
      Linking.removeAllListeners('url');
    };
  }, []);
};

export default useDeepLinking;

I've above hook for handle deep links in my app. where i just use useDeepLinking(); this in my App.tsx.
I've added intent-filter as below in my AndroidManifest.xml.
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="auth" android:pathPrefix="/callback" />
      </intent-filter>

Problem
After selecting the google account from the browser it doesn’t open back my app on android but in metro server i can see the log inside handleURL.

Found what's the issue was.  I had installed @react-native-firebase/app and
@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links in my project. but i wasn't using these or configured these packages since Im using supabase. removing these two packages from project solved the issue.
